# Resume PullSubscription later for EWS

Tags: java, c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

All code examples I've seen kind of work like this

- subscribe to pullsubscription
- get back subscriptionID, watermark
- now loop through getEvents() until done, updating watermark
- possibly unsubscribe.

In short they assume you are doing the pulling in a single thread/process, and
will not need to again pull using the same watermark/subscription ID again.
The API itself doesn't have a "resumePullScription(subscriptionID,watermark). It just
has beginSubscribe(folders,events,watermark). It's unclear to me whether I can
use that watermark again later with another beginSubscribe, since the subscriptionID
cannot be supplied.

- I want to subscribe and get a watermark at time T0
- At another time T1, within the timeout interval I want to getEvents again. This is a separate thread, so I need to reconnect to existing subscription/watermark.

It seems like I have two choices for time T1

- unsubscribe @ time T0,and then resubscribe @ time T1 with watermark, but wont watermark be lost because of the unsubscribe?
- resubscribe passing just the watermark, but will ews be smart enough to hook up to same subscription? or will watermark be ignored? or will subscription budget grow..?

At any rate it's not actually very clear what happens when subscription expires. I would assume watermark would go, but I see info claiming watermark will survive for 30 days. So then, whats the point of subscription id ?

Comment: Not sure why this being voted down ;) It's a practical question IMO - all the examples for PullSubscription seem to more or less assume you will just do all your polling in a single thread and then never need to use the same watermark/subscription ID combo again in another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PullSubscription class in the EWS Manaaged API doesn't have a constructor to allow you to instantiate it by itself (I guess this was a boarder case in their design). So if you want to do this you would need to use either some ProxyCode eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.geteventstype(v=exchg.150).aspx or use raw soap and a httpclass to issue the GetEvents request and parse the result.

Basically while the Subscription is valid (eg within the timeout period) you should be able to  use GetEvents with the SubscriptionId and a valid watermark (the watermark should be good for the 30 days.If you have unsubscribed the event the watermark wouldn't be valid because it would have been removed from the Events Table.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks glen. Surprised it's a border case, but isn't that always the way it is ;)